# Highcharts data will not load using angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to use high charts via angular to take advantage of double binding. I'm having an issue rendering the data, the graph works but the data is not showing up in the chart. When I check the DOM console I can get the array but for some reason its not showing up in the graph.

```
cpvmPartners = [];
cpvmPlannedCpm = [];
actualCpm = [];
graphData = [];
cpvm = [];
plannedPrepared = [];

getData = function(){
     $.getJSON('/cpvmdata', function(data) {
        for(k in data){
            if(data[k]['audience'] == 'GCM'){
                 graphData.push([data[k]['partner'],data[k]['plannedcpm']])
                 actualCpm.push(Math.round((data[k]['mediacost']/data[k]['impressions']*1000)))
                 cpvmPlannedCpm.push(data[k]['plannedcpm'])
                 cpvmPartners.push(data[k]['partner'])
            }
        }
    });
}

prepareData = function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < actualCpm.length; i++) {
        actualPrepared.push({name: "CPM", data: actualCpm[i]})
        plannedPrepared.push({name: "Planned CPM", data: cpvmPlannedCpm[i]})
    }
}

myApp = angular.module('main', ['highcharts-ng']);

myApp.controller('graphController', function ($scope) {
    getData();
    prepareData();
    $scope.highchartsNG = {
      options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: actualCpm
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },
    loading: false
    }
});
```

Comment: is all that code in one file?

Answer (score 0):

So the `getData()` function you call in the angular controller is asynchronous:
By the time you have gotten the data, you have already made your chart in `$scope.highChartNg`

That is why you can see your data the console but you don't actually set it to the `actualCpm` by the time angular is done. To fix this you need to create the chart IN your `$.getJSON` function like so:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    series: [{}]
};

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

You can see more here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

Comment: How do I do this with consideration for Angular scope?

Comment: put all the stuff in your controller...instead of getData(), do $scope.getData = function.... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Easier just to use

> $http.get

Angular service.

Blending jQuery and Angular is troublesome for scoping.

```
$http.get('cpvmdata')
.then(function(response){
    $scope.output = response.data;
    for(k in $scope.output){
        if($scope.output[k]['audience'] == 'GCM'){
            $scope.planned.push($scope.output[k]['plannedcpm'])
            $scope.partners.push($scope.output[k]['partner'])
            $scope.cpm.push(Math.round(($scope.output[k]['mediacost']/$scope.output[k]['impressions']*1000)))
        }
    }
});
```